# Updating Lat/Longs and actual position of point shapefile using arcpy.UpdateCursor()?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, shapefile

I have a point shapefile with over 3000 points that are updated frequently, when they are updated they need to have their lat/longs changed which is entered into the attribute table.

When the lat/longs are updated in the attribute table I notice that the feature does not actually change its position in correlation to the new lat/long entered in the attribute table.

Is there a way to make this happen in ArcView with out having to re-export the attribute table out as a dbf, add it to the map then display xy data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you're updating some attributes of your features instead of updating the actual geometry. You can make changes to a feature's geometry using python but it's a couple extra lines of code. Check out this example:

```
import arcpy
shapeName = arcpy.Describe('c:/path/to/shp/update_geom.shp').shapeFieldName
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(r'c:/path/to/shp/update_geom.shp')
row = rows.next() # just one row...you could iterate through all rows
pnt = arcpy.Point(row.getValue(shapeName).getPart(0).X + 0.5, row.getValue(shapeName).getPart(0).Y + 0.5)
row.setValue(shapeName, pnt)
rows.updateRow(row)
del rows
```

That only updates one row but demonstrates how to update a point feature's geometry.

**Added code that loops over all rows.

```
import arcpy
shapeName = arcpy.Describe('c:/path/to/shp/update_geom.shp').shapeFieldName
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(r'c:/path/to/shp/update_geom.shp')
for row in rows:
  row = rows.next()
  pnt = arcpy.Point(row.getValue(shapeName).getPart(0).X + 0.5, row.getValue(shapeName).getPart(0).Y + 0.5)
  row.setValue(shapeName, pnt)
  rows.updateRow(row)
del rows
```