# How to create a copy of a feature class that is vertically and horizontally offset by a given distance?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I want to duplicate a polygon feature class and offset all of the polygons by about 10 feet in both the x and y directions. Is this possible to do using arcpy, or are there any geoprocessing tools that could help me do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be done with arcpy. Take a look at my post on [updating a feature's geometry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/updating-lat-longs-and-actual-position-of-point-shapefile/2957#2957). Instead of using an update cursor and modifying a the geometry in place, you'd create a new feature class, use a search cursor on your original feature class and write new geometries based on each feature in your original feature class.

Comment: Thanks. Rather than defining a point and shifting it, how would I change this line of code to suite the shifting of a polygon?

pnt = arcpy.Point(row.getValue(shapeName).getPart(0).X + 0.5, row.getValue(shapeName).getPart(0).Y + 0.5)

Answer (score 4):

As stated above, I would export data to a new FC and then turn on editing, select all and use the move command.

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought you'd do a Copy, Paste, then Move.  The Editor menu's Move function lets you specify a delta x and y.  However, I can't seem to find that function in arcpy.