# How to get the specified point coordinates of a Polyline

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor

```
lines_cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lines,["From_id","To_id","SHAPE@"])
for lines_row in lines_cursor:
    from_id = lines_row[0]
    to_id = lines_row[1]
    if from_id in points_dict.keys():
        print from_id
        for point in lines_row[2].getPart(0):
            print point.X, point.Y
```

This will return a coordinates array of all point objects, but i just want to get the first point coordinates(or the second, the third, etc.) and give it to a new value.

How do I get this work?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/updating-lat-longs-and-actual-position-of-point-shapefile was suggested as a Duplicate but I voted to leave this question open because it seems to be asking about changing vertex locations on a polyline using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor() when the other question was changing point locations using arcpy.UpdateCursor().

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are asking this question is almost exactly the same as this GIS
SE [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168508/update-z-values-on-a-line-feature/168515#168515).

This can be a bit tricky with polylines as the x, y, and z-values of each vertice are not immediately accessible through the shape field. You will need to access the polyline geometry object (Shape field) with `SHAPE@` and drill down further to get to each point in the polyline geometry. Here is a `python` and `arcpy` code snippet for how to access the x, y, and z-values of the vertices of each line in a polyline feature class.

```
shift_value = 2
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Breaklines", ['SHAPE@']) as u_cur:
    for row in u_cur:
        geometry = row[0]
        pts = geometry.getPart(0) #get polyline geometry
        pt_array = arcpy.Array() #create array to house new points
        for pt in pts:
            pt.Z += shift_value #shift x,y, or z value (pt.X, pt.Y, pt.Z, to shift x, y, and z values respectively)
            pt_array.add(pt) #add point to array
        new_polyline_geometry = arcpy.Polyline(pt_array, None, True) #important to enable z-value by having the third parameter set to True if you are editing the z-value
        row[0] = new_polyline_geometry #set row[0] which is SHAPE@ (geometry object)
        u_cur.updateRow(row)
```

In a nut shell:

- loop over the vertices of the polyline geometry
- update each x, y, and/or z value of the point geometry
- add the updated point to an array
- once all points in the polyline have been adjusted:

  - create a new polyline geometry with the point array, making sure to set it to z-enabled if you are shifting the z-value
  - then update the old polyline geometry with the newly created geometry

Currently this will only work on the first part of the geometry, see `pts = geom.getPart(0)`, however it can be easily edited to work on the line if it has multiple parts. By updating the code and integrating another loop and using the `.partCount` of the `Polyline` object.

An additional method, suggested by, @DWynne on the GIS SE question mentioned [above](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168508/update-z-values-on-a-line-feature/168515#168515), is to use the `explode_points` option when creating the
`UpdateCursor`. This will eliminate the need to loop over all of the points of each polyline.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After trying many times, i add  another statement(. getObject())  to extract the specific vertex. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this for every row within your cursor:

```
arr = arcpy.Array()
for point in lines_row[2].getPart(0):
    print point.X, point.Y
    arr.add(point)

polyLine = arcpy.Polyline(arr)
row.setValue("SHP", polyLine)
cursor.updateRow(row)
```

or alternatvily use `row.shape = polyline`.

Comment: @Yi.WEI If this question was helpful or even solved your problem you may consider to upvote it or accept it as your answer.